# Addressables: Save/Load to file

Tags: unity-game-engine

Maybe anyone could explain me or point me to some resources: How to save  Addressables to json and read from Json. Then load back to original object with saved data/info? I Just can't find anything about this.

Answer (score 0):

You question is too vague. Include your code sample. Addressables is a complex package on its own.

A json file is recognized by Unity as a text asset file. You can save/load the json file like any other asset in the Addressables package.

Depending on the json library you are using, you can load/save the object to json.

Comment: to load / save objects you don't need addressables. The prefabs / scriptable objects are essentially serialized C# objects. 
You can also just use a json library and save objects to .json assets.